# Lemma $4.2$ of Chapter $8$ of Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

I would like to know why $\varphi(q) = q$ for all $q \in V$ and $f_1^{-1} \circ f_2$ makes sense (i.e., why $f_2(V) \subset f_1(V)$?) in the proof below.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What is a normal neighborhood?

Comment: @PaulFrost see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates

Comment: Why this problem is closed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\gamma: [0,l] \longrightarrow V$ be a geodesic with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma(l) = q$. Remember that geodesics are preserved under isometries, then $f_i(\gamma(t))$ ($i = 1,2$) are geodesics on $N$ and they have same initial point and initial velocity once that $\gamma(0) = p$, $f_1(p) = f_2(p)$ and $(df_1)_p = (df_2)_p$, therefore $f_1(\gamma(t)) = f_2(\gamma(t))$ for all $t \in [0,l]$ from the uniqueness of geodesics, in particular, $f_1(q) = f_1(\gamma(l)) = f_2(\gamma(l)) = f_2(q)$, i. e., $\varphi(q) = q$.

P.S.: the proof above shows that $f_1^{-1} \circ f_2$ is well defined on $V$. Indeed, the proof showed that the composition is well defined on the trace of the geodesic $\gamma$, but, once that we can always joining $p$ to $q$ by a geodesic because $V$ is a normal neighborhood of $p$ and $q \in V$ is arbitrary, the result follows.